# java - Thread IllegalThreadStateException when downloading multiple files

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, arraylist, download

I am trying my hand at multithreading and wanted to implement a little program to download multiple files simultaneously.
I have created a FileDownloader class which extends Thread.

From the main, my idea was to create an ArrayList with all the FileDownload objects in question (allDownloads) and another ArrayList called activeDownloads, where I limit the amout on active downloads to 4.

The program download a few files and then throws this exception. I understand that it is thrown when trying to start a Thread again. But in the program below, I am interrupting a Thread and starting another one up every time a file download is complete, so I don't understand, how can it be that I'm trying to start the SAME Thread?

```
while (allDownloads.size() > 0) {
            while (activeDownloads.size() < 4) {
                if (allDownloads.iterator().hasNext()) {
                    FileDownloader d = allDownloads.iterator().next();
                    activeDownloads.add(d);
                    allDownloads.remove(d);

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < activeDownloads.size(); i++) {
                FileDownloader t = activeDownloads.get(i);
                try {
                    if (!t.isRunning())
                        t.start();
                    else if (t.isFinished()) {
                        t.interrupt();
                        activeDownloads.remove(t);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
                    System.out.println("****Thread cannot be restarted****");
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you put the exception message please, add e.printStackTrace() in the catch clause so we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: Yep: putting an println into your catch block that doesn't even print e's message, that isn't much better than an empty catch block. So, something failed, but why say what exactly ...

Comment: What's the `t.isRunning()` method? I don't think it's part of the `Thread` api.

Comment: Can your post the code of your FileDownloader  class

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is probably here:

```
if (allDownloads.iterator().hasNext()) {
    FileDownloader d = allDownloads.iterator().next();
    ...
}
```

You are supposed to keep the value of `allDownloads.iterator()` in a dedicated variable otherwise you will create a new iterator at each call and then get always the first value so here the same thread.

So the code should be:

```
Iterator<FileDownloader> it = allDownloads.iterator();
while (activeDownloads.size() < 4) {
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        FileDownloader d = it.next();
        activeDownloads.add(d);
        it.remove();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from activeDownloads while iterating over it. Try iterating backwards over the `List` like

```
for (int i = activeDownloads.size()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--) {...}
```

This way your index will still be right when you remove elements form the `List`

Comment: It's not the source of the problem he can of course remove an element while he iterate over the container list I don't see any problem in that !

Comment: Yes but the index will be not correct then.
I.e when you remove the second element of the List, the third will become second etc. So your next get(i) will refer to an unexpected element.

Comment: should that generate an IllegalThreadStateException exception I don't think so?

Comment: otherwise to avoid this he doesn't have to iterating backwards he need just to decrements the index if he removes an element

Comment: Iterating backwards is way more intuitive than modifying the index in the for loop.